# Are Normal variables constructed by CDF inverse of uniform variables indepdent?

Tags: random-variables, independence, gaussian

Let $\Phi$ be the CDF of the normal distribution, and let $u,v,s\sim\mathrm{Unif}[0,1]$ be iid uniform variables, then $X_1:= \Phi^{-1}(u),Y_1:= \Phi^{-1}(v)$ will be independent normal variables, therefore $Z_1:=(X_1+Y_1)/\sqrt{2}$ will follow a normal Gaussian. Now if we shift $u,v$ by $s$ and define $X_2:=\Phi^{-1}(u+s - \lfloor u+s\rfloor ),Y_2:=\Phi^{-1}(v+s - \lfloor v+s\rfloor )$, where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor $ stands for floor, $Z_2:=(X_2+Y_2)/\sqrt{2}$ will all analogously follow the normal Gaussian distribution. My question is, is $Z_1$ independent of $Z_2$?

Answer (score 1):

As $s \to 0+$, $Z_2 \to Z_1$.  So they should certainly not be independent if $s$ is sufficiently small.  I would guess that they are dependent for all $s$, but it'll be a bit messy to prove.

Comment: actually by numerical testing, $s$ near $0$ seems to be the only place that they become dependent, but seem to be independent almost everywhere else.

Comment: Consider, for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $g(s) = \mathbb P(Z_1 < \alpha, Z_2 < \beta) - \mathbb P(Z_1 < \alpha) \mathbb P(Z_2 < \beta)$.  I would think that this is real-analytic as a function of $s$.  If this is the case, and $g(s) \ne 0$ for some $s$, then $g(s) \ne 0$ with at most countably many exceptions.  So they should be **dependent** almost everywhere.

Comment: I did montecarlo experiments: I generated $10^7$ $(Z_1,Z_2)$ pairs this way, and tabulated them in a $20\times20$ histogram grid, and plotted the data  and calculated the obvious Pearson $\chi^2$ number. The histogram did not look flat, and I got off-the-chart chisquare values.  (I used drand48 and the GSL cdf routines.)